How to have multiple query/mutation services i with GraphQL but keep the AddQueryType() and AddMutationType() empty (no static service)
//Desired approach
builder.Services
    .AddGraphQLServer()
    .AddQueryType()
    .AddMutationType();

//Current approach
builder.Services
    .AddGraphQLServer()
    .AddQueryType(d => d.Name("query"))
    .AddTypeExtension<StudioQuery>()
    .AddTypeExtension<AnimeQuery>()
    .AddMutationType(d => d.Name("mutation"))
    .AddTypeExtension<StudioMutation>()
    .AddTypeExtension<AnimeMutation>();

var app = builder.Build();

I think this is possible by having static services, but I do not want to do so.
